# Blank screen in ionic 6 for webview veriosns older than 60

Tags: android, ionic-framework, webview, ionic6

I have a application with ionic 6. I get negative feedback from my client about blank screen in old versions of webview . I checked my debug version and saw in inspect section doesn't exist any html code inside app-root tag. How can I fix this problem

I tried use use chrome engine webview and I can't do this. I wanna use library like crosswalk or use chrome engine webview.

Comment: i facing same issue .. after check the issue from specific plugin use AndroidX can you share your confix.xml and package.json for more details to help you